# develop CMS in Ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

i am new in emberjs, i feel ember is good and well structured mvc framework,

Is it possible to create a Content Management System in Ember ?

i want to create new pages, section in pages,
i thing ember using routes for pages, and i want dynamic pages, the page may have different styles,

```js
this.route('admin',{ resetNamespace: true },function(){
      this.route('dashboard',{ resetNamespace: true }); 
  });
```

can i dynamically generate routes
thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a Content Management System in Ember ?

Yes, it is.

> i want to create new pages, section in pages, i thing ember using
>   routes for pages, and i want dynamic pages, the page may have
>   different styles,

That's possible.

> can i dynamically generate routes thank you in advance

You can use dynamic query params to be able to have custom pages. For example, in admin panel you can have input fields for many things such as page HTML, page style, page JavaScript, page name. Then you store these things in your database. Then if someone navigates for example to app.com/pages/myNewPage then you query database on backend for page with name `myNewPage` and return data to the client. You can use Ember Data for that and create `Page` model. Then in your `pages.someRoute` template (someRoute handles dynamic query params) you use things like:

```
{{{page.content}}}

<style>
{{{page.css}}}
</style>
```

So, yeah, it's totally possible to do.